# How to pass User defined table type values to Value field for the Execute Procedure in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2016

[image]

I have a few value types as parameters to my stored procedure, I am not sure how to input their values into the Value field of SSMS.
Can anyone provide me with the sample? Is it like JSON or Name/Value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform through Query

```
DECLARE @FromFieldDefinitions DFFromFieldDefinition
DECLARE @FieldDefitions DFFieldDefinition
DECLARE @ListParameters DFFieldDefinition
DECLARE @DataBindingParameters DFFieldDefinition

   

INSERT INTO @FromFieldDefinitions values (1, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @FromFieldDefinitions values (2, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @FromFieldDefinitions values (3, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @FromFieldDefinitions values (4, <value1..>, <value2..>)

INSERT INTO @FieldDefitions values (1, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @FieldDefitions values (2, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @FieldDefitions values (3, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @FieldDefitions values (4, <value1..>, <value2..>)

INSERT INTO @ListParameters values (1, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @ListParameters values (2, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @ListParameters values (3, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @ListParameters values (4, <value1..>, <value2..>)


INSERT INTO @DataBindingParameters values (1, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @DataBindingParameters values (2, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @DataBindingParameters values (3, <value1..>, <value2..>)
INSERT INTO @DataBindingParameters values (4, <value1..>, <value2..>)


EXEC Yoursp <other_params>,@FromFieldDefinitions,@FieldDefitions,@ListParameters,@DataBindingParameters,<other_params>
```